# Python - changing the value of an element, within an array, within a dictionary

Tags: python

This is sort of hard to explain. So, I have a text file, "People.txt", containing the following:

```
Jonathan,7,
Laura,11,
Bethany,21,
Jonathan,8,
Ashley,10,
Jonathan,14,
Rachel,10,
Jonathan,5,
```

What I'm trying to do is look for the matches in the file to a specific name, and subtract the number that corresponds with the name from a total of 50.

The focus here is that Jonathan has multiple entries in the file. Currently, my code looks for a match in the file, and subtracts the number from 50. The problem is that it doesn't take into account that the first match has already been 'used'.

(Let's take the name being searched for to be Jonathan)

```
name = "Jonathan"
total = 50

with open("People.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        info = line.split(",")
        if name == info[0]:
            total -= info[1]
```

I'm not sure this example actually works in portraying the problem, as I'm finding it sort of hard to explain the issue. So maybe just ignore it / use it as a general idea as to what I'm trying to do.

Basically the problem I'm having is that my real code (the code here is just a simplified example, as I don't want to post the real thing here) only takes into account the first match each time.
But essentially, how would I make sure that the program moves onto the next match each time? Maybe so that it counts how many matches are in the file, and each time it subtracts from the total, move on to the next match when it reaches it during iterating through the file.

Sorry if this doesn't really make sense. Not sure what example code to use. Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can put all your targeting names in a separate file and read it store in a set, when iterate the people file lines just check whether the name in the set or not. BTW, you have to convert `info[1]` to integer when you subtract it

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer because your code seems fine, it should continue seeking after the first match, and substracting for all matches. But anyways, here's another conceptual solution:

If you read the file into a dictionary, you can then use filter and reduce to do find and subtract the matches.

```
from functools import reduce

name = "Jonathan"
total = 50

namelist = []

with open("People.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        info = line.split(",")
        namelist.append((info[0], int(info[1]))

result = 50 - reduce(lambda x, y: x[1] + y[1], filter(lambda x: x[0] == name, namelist))
```